# How to create multiple new users in a site by using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I followed the instructions from [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356451/how-can-i-create-signup-multiple-new-user-of-my-site-by-using-jmeter-testing-too):

1. Record create user scenario using JMeter.
2. Parametrize add user request (username, details) with `CSV data set config` element.
3. Add `CSV data set config` with required no. of entries (500 in your case) where each line represents user details, user1, India, passwd1, user2, US, passwd2.
4. Add `View result tree`.

When I run this scenario, it displays this error and I don't know why:

> Response code: 500

Can any experts out there share what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: have u passed username and password in http request?

Comment: yes, when I create thread 1 user and input data directly: it passed. But when I use CSV the result is fail

Comment: you have to identify dynamic elelemnt in each http request, then extract each responce from json path extractor , save that var in dynamic variable in jmeter varieble and pass in next request...now  post your output snap

Comment: HTTP status 500 is an internal error on the server https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Comment: @sameerjoshi: I cannot post pic here. How can I send it for you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 500 stands for [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) so first thing you should do when you see it is checking your application log files, most probably you will find the cause of the problem there.

Also be aware that record and replay won't work in 100% of times, modern web applications widely use dynamic request parameters and headers mostly for client state management and security reasons so you will need to take them into consideration as well so your test plan would look like:

- Open Login Page

  - Get all dynamic parameters using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Perform Login providing credentials from the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and dynamic parameters from the previous step.

The process is known as **[correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)** and you should be able to find a lot of information over the web on it. Given JMeter will send the same requests as the real browser - you should be receiving the same responses.

Also add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, it automatically detects and handles [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and deals with cookie-based authentication

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is a Load testing tool and not a data creation tool.

- It should be used for load testing and not functional aspects. Though it can be used for data creation because of its record and replay feature. (of course with parametrization)

To create data,

1. You need to record create user scenario using JMeter.
2. Parametrize add user request (username,details)with csv data set config element.
3. Add CSV data set config with required no. of entries (500 in your case) where each line represents user details, user1,India,passwd1 user2,US,passwd2.
4. Run script with 500 threads (not advisable but a possible way) or single thread with 500 loop count.
   This will create users with data from csv. After that you can load test your website.